# MYSQL - Add multiple users to a table column

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Maybe it's because I don't understand how to search for the right verbiage, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to attach multiple users to a table with multiple columns.

Here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
table name: user   

   user_id    user_name
   1          abc
   2          xyz  
   3          pqr
   4          new  


table2 name : brackets

    id             user_id    bracket_name
    1              4,2        bracket_1
    2              4,3,1      bracket_2 
    3              2,1        bracket_3
    4              3,4,2      bracket_4
```

-- OR --

```
table name: user   

   user_id    user_name  brackets_id
   1          abc        2,3
   2          xyz        1,3,4
   3          pqr        2,4
   4          new        1,2,4


table2 name : brackets

    brackets_id    user_id    bracket_name
    1              4,2        bracket_1
    2              4,3,1      bracket_2 
    3              2,1        bracket_3
    4              3,4,2      bracket_4
```

I'm using nodejs and sequalize as my ORM and understand enough to read, write, delete and update to these tables, but when it comes to organizing my data, I'm completely lost!

Is it possible to add an array to MYSQL with the user ID's or the brackets that the user is allowed to access? The bracket are generated by a user and then they can invite their friends to join a bracket. Users can join multiple brackets and join other brackets as users.

Any guidance would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a Junction Table would simplify this for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

It would look something like:

```
table name: user   

user_id    user_name
1          abc       
2          xyz        
3          pqr        
4          new        


table2 name : brackets

brackets_id        bracket_name
1                  bracket_1
2                  bracket_2 
3                  bracket_3
4                  bracket_4

table3 your junction table:

user_id     brackets_id      
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           3
2           4

etc.etc.
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as this never occurred to me! But, couldn't this thing get REALLY large? And how would this affect performance?

Comment: It may get large as in "have a lot of rows" (depending on your data set) but if you reason though it, you'll see that the actual amount of data you are storing won't really be any larger and could be less storage, particularly after updates (* I'll skip the tl;dr part but am admittedly generalizing). More importantly, relational databases know how to work with this kind of data through joins. There are other benefits as well (for example, using a junction table for n:m associations means you only need to touch one table to add an association between a user and a bracket, as opposed to two).

Comment: Ray's answer is correct, as is Barry's support.  To think about the relationships slightly differently, think of User and Bracket as "nouns" and what is normally referred to in referential databases as a "join table" as a "verb".  In the case the verb is "be belongs to" so the best name for this join table would be "User_belongs_to_Bracket", or more simply, "User_in_Bracket".